# CakePHP 2.4: Model->create() returns no id

Tags: php, cakephp, auto-increment

When register action tries to save data nothing happens and user gets returned to same page

after some debugging I found when running '$this->Participant->create()' it returns no new id

```
if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
    if (!isset($this->data['Participant']['typeSel'])) {
        $regType = $this->data['Participant']['type'];

        // for pilots and visitors, copy the name/email from TeamMember to Participant
        if ($regType == 'pilot' || $regType == 'visitor') {
            $this->request->data['Participant']['name'] =
                    ucwords(strtolower($this->request->data['TeamMember'][0]['first_name'])) . ' '
                            . ucwords(strtolower($this->request->data['TeamMember'][0]['family_name']));
            $this->request->data['Participant']['email'] = $this->request->data['TeamMember'][0]['email'];
        }

        // mark valid inside the team (if not joining)
        if ($regType != 'jointeam') {
            foreach ($this->request->data['TeamMember'] as & $teamMember) {
                $teamMember['validate_inteam'] = 'yes';
                if ($regType == 'visitor') {
                    $teamMember['free_entrance'] = 'yes';
                    $teamMember['num_tables'] = 0;
                }
            }
            $numTeamMembers = count($this->data['TeamMember']);
        }

        // set password
        $this->request->data['Participant']['password'] =
                Security::hash($this->data['Participant']['password1'], null, true);

        // perform registration itself
        if ($regType == 'jointeam') {
            $this->TeamMember->create($this->request->data);
            if ($this->TeamMember->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your registration was recorded. An email was dispatched to the team coordinator for approval.');

                $this->Mail->sendTeamValidationEmail(
                        $this->Participant->findById($this->data['TeamMember']['participant_id']));
                $this->redirect(array(
                        'controller' => 'pages',
                        'action' => 'welcome'));
            }
            else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your registration could not be completed. Please try again.');
            }
        }
        else {
            $this->Participant->create(); // $this->Participant->id remains empty
            if ($this->Participant->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your registration was recorded. You will receive an email with further details during the next 24 hours.');

                $this->Mail->sendConfirmEmail($this->Participant->findById($this->Participant->id));
                $this->redirect(array(
                        'controller' => 'pages',
                        'action' => 'welcome'));
            }
            else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your registration could not be completed. Please try again.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the create function to add the id. 
There seems to be no problem with the DB because you can log in and fetch data on other controllers

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding what those methods do.

```
$this->Participant->create();
```

It clears the model (unsets the id), so does the exact opposite of what you expect.
This method is needed for Cake to actually make it possible to create a new record using save(), saveMany(), saveAll() etc.

Those methods then set the Model->id again (after a successful save of course).

Also, using saveAll() you should rather look at callbacks if you need those IDs, as it can only provide you with the id of the last stored record then this way (it will overwrite it for each save).

Comment: Didn't know that, Is there a way to get more info on why the saveAll() did not return true?

Comment: debug() it - what does it return. My guess: an array of multiple trues if you are not using atomic saves here. My trick to just return a boolean in this case, as well, was [this](https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/Model/MyModel.php#L395).

Comment: using `debug($this->Participant->saveAll($this->request->data))` it returns a single False

Comment: Then look at `$this->Participant->validationErrors`, what does that array contain?

Comment: `array(
 'current_password' => array(
  (int) 0 => 'Password must match your current password'
 )` which is used during changepwd action but not in this one
)

Comment: There is your problem.. It is also triggered here, because your model callbacks are probably faulty. Tip: [working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/).